# UnsupportedOperationException while building a Kotlin project in Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

When I try to build my Kotlin project I get the following [error](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/72d7c1263adace5248bcbd43dee80746) in Idea:

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression at (60,19) in E:/altruix-is/src/main/kotlin/com/mycompany/myproduct/capsulecrm/CapsuleCrmSubsystem.kt:
client.execute(req)

[...]

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: doSubstitute with no original should not be called for synthetic extension
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.synthetic.SamAdapterFunctionsScope$MyFunctionDescriptor.doSubstitute(SamAdapterFunctionsScope.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.impl.FunctionDescriptorImpl$CopyConfiguration.build(FunctionDescriptorImpl.java:553)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.ErasedOverridabilityCondition.isOverridable(ErasedOverridabilityCondition.kt:47)
```

The error seems to occur in calls

```
res = client.execute(req)
```

where `client` is Apache HttpClient.

[image: Screenshot]

The source file, where this occurs can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dpisarenko/6ddcf5b29c6cbed10528501ff4599986).

I submitted the bug report to JetBrains, but I need to work further on the project and therefore a work around. Note that until yesterday everything worked fine. Yesterday I upgraded the Kotlin plugin to the most recent version, maybe that's the problem.

How can I avoid the error above?

**Update 1 (03.03.2017 14:46 MSK):**

This doesn't work:

```
open fun addNote(note: String, compId: Long): ValidationResult {
    val client = httpClient
    if (client == null) {
        return ValidationResult(false, "Internal error")
    }

    var res: CloseableHttpResponse? = null
    var req: HttpUriRequest?
    try {
        req = composeAddNoteRequest(note, compId)
        res = client.execute(req)
        if (res.statusLine.statusCode != 201) {
            logger.error("addNote(note='$note', compId=$compId): Wrong status code ${res.statusLine.statusCode}")
            return ValidationResult(false, "Wrong status code (CRM interaction)")
        }
        return ValidationResult(true, "")
    }
    catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        logger.error("addNote(note='$note', compId=$compId)", throwable)
        return ValidationResult(false, "Database error")
    } finally {
        close(res)
    }
    return ValidationResult(false, "Internal logic error")
}
```

This works (difference is in the second line from the top):

```
open fun addNote(note: String, compId: Long): ValidationResult {
    val client = httpClient as CloseableHttpClient // Change
    if (client == null) {
        return ValidationResult(false, "Internal error")
    }

    var res: CloseableHttpResponse? = null
    var req: HttpUriRequest?
    try {
        req = composeAddNoteRequest(note, compId)
        res = client.execute(req)
        if (res.statusLine.statusCode != 201) {
            logger.error("addNote(note='$note', compId=$compId): Wrong status code ${res.statusLine.statusCode}")
            return ValidationResult(false, "Wrong status code (CRM interaction)")
        }
        return ValidationResult(true, "")
    }
    catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        logger.error("addNote(note='$note', compId=$compId)", throwable)
        return ValidationResult(false, "Database error")
    } finally {
        close(res)
    }
    return ValidationResult(false, "Internal logic error")
}
```

Comment: That's why it is comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example above, `client.execute(req)` returns `HttpResponse`, which is not a sub-type of `CloseableHttpResponse`. So, type mismatch error is correct. Either you should use `CloseableHttpClient` here, or cast `client.execute(req)` to `CloseableHttpResponse`.

I couldn't reproduce `KotlinFrontEndException` from your example. From the stack trace provided I can deduce that something wrong happened with "SAM adapters" - that is, when you use a Kotlin lambda in a Java method call that accepts single abstract method (SAM) interface. 
Please, file a bug here if the problem still occurs: http://kotl.in/issue